# Leaflet don't shown the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I don't know why the map does not show up.
I do this

Add in my head the cdn

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
 integrity="sha512- 
 xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
 crossorigin=""/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
 integrity="sha512- 
 gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
 crossorigin=""></script>
```

Then I created a div

```
<div id="map" style="height:180px"></div>
```

And in my script have this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [38.9765, -1.855],
        zoom: 13
    });
</script>
```

But it does not work and I don't have any error.

[image]

Comment: Note: the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a tile layer using `L.tileLayer()`

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [38.9765, -1.855],
  zoom: 13
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512- xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512- gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height:180px"></div>
```